# How to make the container don't go larger than the screen view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been making image matching game, I've two problems, The first one is that The box on the desktop-view give a scroll bar and i want all the box to appear in the screen without need to scroll. The second problem is that how to make the image box have some color and when the user tab on it, it shows the image, here is my cods:

```js
const makeImagesWork = () => images.forEach((name, i) => images[i] = `https://loremflickr.com/420/420?lock=${(i + 1) % 2 + i}&random=${name}`);
const box = document.getElementById('box');

images = ["Apple.jpg", "Apple.jpg", "Orange.jpg", "Orange.jpg", "Cake1.jpg", "Cake1.jpg", "Car.jpg", "Car.jpg", "House1.jpg", "House1.jpg", "Cake2.jpg", "Cake2.jpg", "House2.jpg", "House2.jpg", "Cake4.jpg", "Cake4.jpg"];

makeImagesWork(); // for testing
l = images.length;
let output = '';

function shuffle(a) {
  for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
  }
  return a;
}

images = shuffle(images);

for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  output += `<div class="col-3 imgs">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src=${String(images[i])} alt="image">
                </div>`
}

box.innerHTML = output;
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.imgs {
  border: 2px solid rgb(199, 27, 27);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">


  <!-- External CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Match Images</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="box">

    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Bootsrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

anyone can help me to do that ?

Comment: i dont see any scrollbar ?

Comment: See the project here : https://ayman-tarig.github.io/images-game/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all your screen view is increasing because of images size, so you can control it by adding class `img` in that,

**Scroll problem**

you need to add `disply: block` and `margin: auto` for center image.

**HTML**

```
<img class="img-fluid img" src="Apple.jpg" alt="image">
```

**CSS**

```
img {
    height: 200px;  /* you can set height by your perspective */
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    opacity: 0; /* add for your second problem */
}
```

**2nd problem solution**

```
$('.col-3 img').click(function() {
   $(this).css('opacity',1);
})
```

that solve your scroll problem

[image]

Comment: i added the img class on the container

Comment: simply add above 3 CSS propery in your `img tag`

Comment: i helped you lot in discussion, so don't forgot to consider up-vote and check this answer as best answer for you by clicking on right arrow, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you need to add below code in your css

```
.imgs > img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 80%;
    z-index: -1;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 6px;
}

.imgs {
    text-align: center;
    height: 24vh;
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.imgs.clicked > img {
    z-index: 0;
}

.imgs.clicked {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

this will get rid of vertical scrollbar and to appear image on click only you just need to add/toggle class `clicked` on `imgs` div

this is how it will look

[image]

on that `clicked` class I wrote some css which will work as per your requiremtn

Comment: The images doesn't appear when i click on them

Comment: you need to add class `clicked` on parent div `imgs`

Comment: bro that is not valid css you wrote

Comment: oh can you tell me what is not valid

Comment: see my answer, you dont want to specify height or give postion

Comment: @NishargShah I dont think your provided answer will fix what OP has ask

Comment: @aymantarig you just need to add/toggle `clicked` class see image which I posted in answer, happy coding

Comment: What is add/toggle clicked class ?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the height of the container to 100%. This will make it the same height as its parent.

```
<div class="container" style="height:100%">
```

Comment: I try that and it doesn't work, see the project in this link in order to understand what i mean: https://ayman-tarig.github.io/images-game/